# FormsAuthentication.signout() is not working when acessing application using other pc

Tags: asp.net, logout, global-asax, formsauthentication, formsauthenticationticket

I'm using following code for log out:

```cs
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
Session.Abandon();
FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
```

the above code is working fine when I'm accessing my application from my pc. but if I hit my application from other pc connected in same network, cookie is not deleted and application is not logged out.

Comment: Is this ASP.NET? Then please add the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Users can still browse your website because cookies are not cleared when you call     `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()` and they are authenticated on every new request. In MS documentation is says that cookie will be cleared but they don't, bug? Its exactly the same with `'Session.Abandon()',` cookie is still there.

You should change your code to this:

```
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Session.Abandon();

  // clear authentication cookie
  HttpCookie cookie1 = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");
  cookie1.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
  Response.Cookies.Add(cookie1);

  // clear session cookie (not necessary for your current problem but i would recommend you do it anyway)
  HttpCookie cookie2 = new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", "");
  cookie2.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
  Response.Cookies.Add(cookie2);
  FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
```

Comment: HI, still i'm having problem, the above code just clearing the session data alone, the cookie is stil there. Is there any possible ways to make the ticket expire?

Comment: In my application in global.asax page i'm just checking the condition like'if(cookie!=null){if (!ticket.Expired){......}' so cookie is always expired one the solution might be 1.deleteing the cookie or make the ticket to expire